# Ionic v4 ion-slides problems

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ion-slides

I have created a component in my project that is purely an `ion-slides` UI component. I've injected into the main page of my side-drawer template app and I'm experiencing a number of issues/annoyances:

1. The content doesn't always center within the main pane. It seems as though the width of the individual `ion-slide` items all get set with an inline element style width that is greater than the pane width! I've realised that this only happens when the whole app is loaded.  If I click on the side menu item of the page to reload it individually, the issue disappears. This leads me to believe it's an issue with the order that components are rendered.  Can anyone help me understand what is happening? Is it a bug?

[Undesired behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5WSZ.gif)

2. I can't work out how to get navigation arrows to display/work - is this possible?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ionic4-test-yuppm1?embed=1&file=src/app/app.module.ts

The above Stackblitz should help to give you an idea of my setup but it doesn't show the problem I'm experiencing.  It does show one other peculiarity though:

3. With loop set to true in the options, when you get to the last slide and you go to the next slide, it jumps to second element rather than the first!  Any help on understanding why this is happening will be appreciated.

Thanks